# Getting items from a database not working as expected

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I'm learning PHP and I've hit a wall.

When the user submits to the form, it adds to the database.

I am also trying to display all items in the database on the same page as the form.

However,this only works if the form has **just** been submitted. If the form has not been submitted (but there is still content in the database), nothing is shown.

How can I *always* show what is in the current database?

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="todo_content" id="">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php 

if ( isset($_POST['todo_content'])) {
    $latest_content = $_POST['todo_content'];

} else {
    die();
}
    $todo_db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysqli_select_db($todo_db, 'todo_list');
            mysqli_query(
            $todo_db, 
            "INSERT INTO todo_items (item_content) VALUES ('$latest_content')"
                );
$all_todos = mysqli_query( $todo_db, "SELECT item_content FROM todo_items" );
$all_todos_result = mysqli_fetch_array($all_todos);

var_dump($all_todos_result); // these show nothing
var_dump($all_todos);  // these show nothing

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your insert query inside your if condition and you will need not to die if the form is not submitted but print the form and your query results

```
$todo_db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysqli_select_db($todo_db, 'todo_list');

if ( isset($_POST['todo_content'])) {
    echo 'is set';
    $latest_content = $_POST['todo_content'];

    mysqli_query($todo_db, "INSERT INTO todo_items (item_content) VALUES ('$latest_content')");

} else {

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="todo_content" id="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    $all_todos = mysqli_query( $todo_db, "SELECT item_content FROM todo_items" );
    $all_todos_result = mysqli_fetch_array($all_todos);

    var_dump($all_todos_result);
    var_dump($all_todos);      
}
```

As side note i'd say you are at high risk of mysql injection. You should use prepaed statments and not inserting `$_POST` data inside your database directly

Comment: Thanks for the tip on injection -- this is the first time I've played with this so I'm going ultra-simple to begin with. Do you know of a good tutorial/resource for that?

Comment: You are welcome dude. You can check mysqli wiki on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysqli/info

Answer (score 1):

The `die()` is your problem:

```
if ( isset($_POST['todo_content'])) {
    echo 'is set';
    $latest_content = $_POST['todo_content'];

} else {
    die();
}
```

If `$_POST` is not set, you will never reach the part where you start printing your items. And since the form is not submitted, `$_POST` is empty.

**EDIT**

You could do it like this:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="todo_content" id="">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php 

$todo_db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysqli_select_db($todo_db, 'todo_list');

if ( isset($_POST['todo_content'])) {
    $latest_content = $_POST['todo_content'];
    mysqli_query($todo_db, "INSERT INTO todo_items (item_content) VALUES ('$latest_content')");
}  

$all_todos = mysqli_query( $todo_db, "SELECT item_content FROM todo_items" );
$all_todos_result = mysqli_fetch_array($all_todos);

var_dump($all_todos_result); // these show nothing
var_dump($all_todos);  // these show nothing

 ?>
```